# Is it polite to ask my interviewer to forward an email to another interviewer?

Tags: professionalism, interviewing, email

I've just finished a technical phone interview. I would like to send a thank you note to both of my interviewers, as well as discuss some of the mistakes I made during the technical questions.

The situation is; I only had the junior interviewer's email. I sent the email and addressed all my thoughts regarding the interview. Within the email, I mentioned that:

> I didn't get a chance to get the other interviewer's email address. I was wondering if you would be willing to pass it along so I can send a thank you note to him as well.

I thought "pass it along" means "forward my email to the other interviewer". I got my interviewer's response right away says:

> Thanks for your email. I am not sure I am allowed to pass his email address to you.

My question is:

1. I didn't get the chance to have the senior interviewer's name and email, but I want to say thank you to him. Is it polite to send email to senior interviewer without name?
2. Is it polite to ask junior interviewer to forward my email? Would that be overdo at this point?

Disclaimer: I searched [suggestions](http://www.prepary.com/interviewers-email-address/) when people face the same situation before this post. Unfortunately, the "it" confusion was starting from there...

Comment: I'm not sure why this has been downvoted as it appears to be on topic. My guess is that it's a little hard to read, so I've edited the formatting slightly to make it easier. If I've over-edited it and the question no longer states your intent, please feel free to roll it back.

Comment: PS. I've removed your "English isn't my native language" apology. Your English is really good, and you shouldn't ever apologise for trying.

Comment: Thank you for editing my question especially removing unnecessary information. This helps me to know how to write efficiently.

Comment: Thanks for your encouragement. You are really nice. I am frustrated to get downvotes, but I am also eager to know the reason behind that. Hope there is mechanism behind stackExchange so that I could know how to improve.

Comment: You are probably getting down votes because your title asks if it's polite to ask someone to forward your email, but most of your question text is about how you already did so and were misunderstood. I don't understand how your question follows from your described situation. I think you should be asking about why your email was misunderstood on a stack that deals with language. The fact that the answer you accepted is explaining why your English is confusing rather than answering your question about politeness reinforces my thoughts.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I was facing the situation that I need to make a choice between 1) Asking junior interviewer to forward my email which I don't feel comfortable to do that. Hence that's my title. @Snow offer ideas that it can be a simple sentence. 2) I want to clarify that I am not asking for senior interviewer's email.

Comment: It's better to ask them to forward the email internally. I, for one, would not feel comfortable with people randomly sharing my email with people outside the company.

Comment: But you **already did ask** him to forward your email. He just misunderstood what you were asking. Why are you suddenly uncomfortable asking when you have already done it?

Comment: So I'm wondering ... you know the first interviewer's name, and their email, and I'm guessing you're capable of identifying the pattern in their email addresses, and surely you have the names of both people you were interviewing with (because either they sent it to you first, or at the very least, you wrote it down in your notes so you couldn't possibly forget it during the interview) - the fact that you need to ask anyone for the second interviewer's email is a negative reflection.

Comment: @theonlydanever I think that English not being the OP's native language does have an affect on this question, though not as they intended. As an apology here in the question, it is off topic. However, that does explain the reason for the ambiguity in their email. When I read the first quote, I completely missed the ambiguity the phrasing created and read it as OP intended. After reading the accepted answer, I saw the ambiguity.

Comment: @corsiKa Unfortunately, I did not know the senior's name as he mentioned once at the very beginning of the interview. It is very blurred. Hence, I cannot guess the pattern. Might be another topic: will you ask your interviewer's name spelling so that you can send a thank you note later?

Comment: @Ying, you mention that you also wanted to "discuss some of the mistakes I made during the technical questions", but the "My question is" part doesn't address that (and I think the answers might be different, depending on whether you're still interested in a technical discussion with the other interviewer). Maybe it's best to remove the "discuss some of the mistakes" part, and/or to ask it as a separate question? Not sure what the Workplace policy would be.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

The problem isn't in your use of the phrase "pass it along", it's with the following bit that says "so I can send a thank you note to him as well".

That last bit sounds like you are asking for the senior's email address.  This put the junior into a difficult position of not knowing whether it would be appropriate to share that email address with you.

You would have been better off saying:

> I do not have the other interviewer's email address.  Please share this message with him.

Comment: The *"pass it along"* bit sounds like asking for the email address as well. In context, the "it" can only refer to *"the other interviewer's email address"*. The second sentence then rather reinforces that reading.

Comment: Yeah, it's not grammatical to use "it" as OP intended. "it" has to refer to something mentioned previously. It doesn't mean "this".

Answer (score 17):

You don't need to request the other interviewers email address.

Say something like

> Please pass on my thanks to xx

That should be enough.  There's no need to overcomplicate this.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Does "pass it along" the same as "pass my thanks"?

Comment: It's ambiguous, which is why the interviewer was confused and thought you wanted the other guy's email address.  If you just say "please pass my thanks onto xxx", it will be understood.

Comment: It needs more complication. Someone very smart said things should be as simple as possible, but no simpler.  In the case, requesting that your personally written thank you be forwarded, could result in a more positive impression on the other interviewer, as compared to “pass along my thanks”.  In fact, I would bet that the latter request is not even granted as often as the first request would be, because the latter request is more easily dismissed as a figure of speech or insignificant formality.

Answer (score 4):

The way you’ve written the sentence “it” refers to the other interviewer’s email address when you are trying to make “it” refer to your message that you’ve sent.

The way to resolve this is to directly ask them to forward your message OR restructure the sentence.

“Pass it along” sounds more casual and friendly. If you choose to stick with that you would need to make it obvious that you are asking him to pass along your message.

“I don’t have an email address for the other interviewer. Would you please pass my message along to him as well?”

Whenever you use a pronoun, make sure it is clear which noun it is substituting.

Comment: I think it's actually *unambiguously* a request for the email address. There's no way "it" can refer to "this message" since "this message" has not been mentioned before. If he'd said "please pass this along", it would be ambiguous as to whether the the "this" referred to "this message" or "this email address".

Comment: @Blorgbeard you’re right. I think I was trying to give it more credit because I was swayed by the other content of the post. Editing

Answer (score 3):

It is perfectly polite to ask for him to do that. Unfortunately, as others have already said, your request wasn't worded as well as it could have been and it did come across as if you were asking for their email. That's not necessarily a faux pas, but it's reasonable for him to have declined your (perceived) request.

**But** what's done is done. There's no use now in agonising over the wording or the level of ambiguity in what you said (as some other users seem to be doing).

What I would do now is send a very short email just to clarify. Something like:

> Apologies for the misunderstanding. What I meant to ask was whether
>   you would pass along my thanks on my behalf.

If you encounter yourself in a similar situation in the future, you can say:

> Blah blah blah. Thank you for your time on Tuesday.
>
> I do not have his email address so please also pass along my thanks to Mr Foo.